# How can I provide a `java.nio.file.WatchService` for OS X myself with Oracle JDK 7/8?

Tags: java, nio

For OS X there is [no native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362404/682376) `WatchService` implementation in the JDKs 7, 8 and 9. I would like to be able to use both the `WatchService` interface transparently **and** have native file watching instead of polling on OS X.

Is there a way I can provide a new `WatchService` for OS X? I would like to do this transparently instead of on every place where I ask for a `WatchService` with:

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

A suggested fix is to add the `SensitivityWatchEventModifier.HIGH` argument to calls to register. However, this value comes from sun packages and is only available on the Oracle JDK and I would prefer not to have such a dependency.

Comment: Using what native code?

Comment: @EJP: E.g. the [BarbaryWatchService](https://github.com/gjoseph/BarbaryWatchService/tree/master/src/main/java/com/barbarysoftware/watchservice) library has bindings to the native interface. If I could transparently add that it would be great.